# Reactjs/Flux : When actions depend on async actions

Tags: asynchronous, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

Reactjs 0.14.0 , Vanilla Flux

Async Actions dependencies are a constant conceptual struggle. I've looked at this for months(dead serious) and every similar thread just doesn't make plain what I think is one of the hardest parts of the React/Flux learning curve.

**The Problem:**

**If you want ActionB to be carried out one time directly after ActionA is done it's not really obvious at all where to put that to be updated by the View as the Flux pattern suggests( cause supposedly ActionA->ActionB chaining is an anti-pattern)**

Note: maybe componentDidUpdate is the best that can be done, but it implies that ActionB can be called many times needlessly.

**What I'm Trying to Do**

So I'm using [the common ActionA->WebAPI->Action->Dispatcher->Stores->View->ActionB](https://github.com/facebook/flux)

Which in most cases flows like this:

ActionA->WebAPI->Action(Async)->Dispatcher->Stores->View->ActionB

And often it is the case that ActionB is dependent on the Payload data of ActionA to be ready in it's store.(waitFor() was not designed for async situations like this supposedly.)

Example:

**Main.js**

```
componentWillMount: function(){
    AuthActionCreators.checkForSession((loggedIn) => { //THIS IS A CALLBACK TO DO AN ACTION DEPENDENT ON USER DATA BEING IN THE USERSTORE
      if(loggedIn){
        AnotherActionCreators.updateAnotherStoreNowUserStuffIsInStores(this.props.someProp);//Action->Action(supposedly an anti-pattern)
      }
    });
},
```

**AuthActionCreators.js**

```
//Problem #1 Pointless Middle-Men Actions When Using The Pattern: ActionToServer->WebAPIUtils->ActionWithPayload
//Note: Many say to not call WebAPIUtils directly in Components

checkForSession: function(callback){

   /* Notice how this action SEEMED to not need the dispatcher
    because its a call to a server and I wait for a return to call an Action 
    that can actually dispatch a payload)*/

    WebAPIUtils.hasSession(callback);
  },
```

**WebAPIUtils.js**

```
//Problem #2 Async Actions calling dependent Actions 
//ActionA -> ActionB is supposedly an anti pattern instead of :ActionA -> Dispatcher -> Store -> View -> ActionB 
  var hasSession = function(callbackDepOnUserData) {
    let jwt = localStorage.getItem('jwt');
    if (jwt) {
        $.ajax(this.href, {
            success: function(userData) {
                ServerActionCreators.receiveUserPayloadInStore(userData);//Async Action that will actually sends a payload(I'm kinda okay with this action)
                callbackDepOnUserData(true);//This callback(which is an action)feels like an anti-pattern but it the only way to call after dependent data is
                                            //available in store 
            },
        });
   }
   else{
    console.log("does not have a session");
   }
 }
```